# Can't remember tool used to create geometry from curve

Tags: modeling

[image]

It's been a while since I've used Blender and I forgot the tool I used to create this object. I know that I made it by using the Curve Pen, then a tool/modifier that gave it thickness, then a Remesh modifier to give it better geometry. The tool in question made the geometry almost like voxels, where points that were close together created merged geometry, like the center area in my model. Does this sound familiar to anyone? It was very useful because I was able to quickly create this shape.

Answer (score 2):

You can give curve thickness by adjusting its bevel depth in the Properties Editor, Data tab, Geometry panel, Bevel sub-panel.You can then adjust radius of its individual points, convert the curve to mesh and remesh it. Voxel remesh will join touching parts and quad remesh will make topology nicer.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rADn3.png]

Comment: Hi Martynas,
Thanks for the help. Your method works, but finally figured out what I was looking for. I was wrong about having used a Curve, it was just vertices put into a Skin Modifier. Thanks again!